Action movie of a father avenging the murder of his daughter
For the longest time, I had this movie stuck in my head and always believed it was part of the Taken movie series but just had a similar concept to it. Also, sorry for the bad movie description—I only remember bits of it, so I'll try to explain what I remember.
This movie is about a man, a father avenging the murder of his daughter.
The movie kind of starts with the man identifying his daughter in the morgue, believing it was a drive-by or something. The whole plot of the movie is that the man goes after the people who are connected to the death of his daughter, who are either from a gang or from the mafia, and goes after each member, gaining information about the man at the top of it all. Once he gets to the man, he asks him why he killed his daughter but finds out that the man and his organization really had nothing to do with the death of his daughter.
Then at the ending, once the man goes home, he gets contacted by either his daughter's friend or boyfriend and learns the truth of what really happened the night of his daughter's death. His daughter and her friend were hanging out and drinking when she brought out her father's gun to show off to her friends. They went outside to the front yard to mess with the gun, and they each took turns holding it and aiming it. But once one of the friends had it and started pointing the gun at them, the daughter tried to take it away, but the guy accidentally pulled the trigger and shot the daughter right in the head. The boys threw the gun and ran away.
It's an American action movie; I don't remember who stars in it. The movie probably came out sometime around 2010–2016. So please, someone tell me what this movie is because it's been stuck in my head for years now, and I'm getting frustrated not knowing what it is. I've tried everything to find out the movie title, so thank you ahead of time.

Edge of Darkness? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hVOH8xrCI9I&ab_channel=ClaudeGongalves - Probably the girl is far too young to be a match.

I found a similar question on IMBD and someone suggested Mystic River as the answer: https://community-imdb.sprinklr.com/conversations/i-need-to-know/movie-about-father-seeking-revenge-for-daughters-accidental-death/66b5887fa505f3636e131183

Does it involve torture and the wife also dying? Some parts, but not all, sound like Law Abiding Citizen - https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1197624/?ref_=nm_flmg_job_1_cred_t_29

I believe you're looking for the movie "EVERY LAST ONE OF THEM" by Paramount Movies. Trailer link: 



OP already accepted another answer. Is there a reason to think that this is actually the correct one?

Also, the OP says it's a movie from 2010–2016, so it can't be this one from 2021.
